# How to clean memory in Share Extension for iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension

For some reason there is a lot of messages `Received memory warning.` Sometimes this occur along with `_BSMachError: (os/kern) invalid capability (20)`. I do not know what is going on. I read a lot of questions how to solve this, but with no success.

This is my class:

```
class WLShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController {}
```

I do completely nothing inside, but still get memory warnings.

May it be because storyboard is too complicated?

This is my storyboard:

[image]

I removed almost everything from code for every of that three controllers, but still got warnings.

I know that there is limited memory for extensions, but do not know even how to check it.

**IMPORTANT QUESTION:**

This doesnt happen for every app that running my extension. Just for specific one. 
**Is it possible that memory warning is because of the app that running my extension?**

Comment: I am getting same error , do you have any solution ?